# Is there an equivalent of the PaperTrail gem in Rails for NodeJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, version-control, paper-trail-gem

I'm looking for something for NodeJS that is similar to the PaperTrail gem for rails. Something that will automatically help keep track of changes to different fields.

Comment: Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoshEmory did you ever find a node tool like PaperTrail?  I am searching for one as well.

Comment: @user2517182 I know this is an old comment but look at the answer below and it might help.

Comment: @JoshEmory thanks!  I don't need it anymore though, and most of these repos look abandoned.

Comment: @user2517182 Yea, on a second look through most of them do. But might be good base to start for someone who does need it. Glad to hear you solved your solution though.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are multiple Node.js ports of PaperTrail available on NPM. Some are customized for specific adaptors such as Winston or Sequelize.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/papertrail
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-papertrail
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-paper-trail

Comment: These packages are for sending logs to a service called [SolarWinds Papertrail](https://www.papertrail.com/). They will not help you to revert or undelete a model like the [paper_trail gem](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail).